# Complex Integration using Cauchy's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

The problem is the integration of 
$$I=\int_{\left\lvert z-1\right\rvert=1} f(z) dz$$
where 
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^3-1}$$
and the path goes $1$ loop in positive direction.

I tried to solve the problem using Cauchy's Theorem by finding $z$ that makes $f(z)$ denominator be $0$. That was $z=1$.

And I got struck.

I think the integral is needed to be treat somehow so that

$$\int_{C_a}\frac{1}{(z-\alpha)^n}dz = 2{\pi}i \text{ when } n=1$$

can be used.

My question is how should I continue with the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only pole of $f(z)$ on the circle is $z=1$

According to residue theorem
$$\oint _{\gamma }f(z)\,dz=2\pi i \operatorname {Res} (f,1)$$
And we have $\operatorname {Res} (f,1)=\lim_{z\to 1} \, \dfrac{z-1}{z^3-1}=\lim_{z\to 1} \, \dfrac{1}{z^2+z+1}=\dfrac{1}{3}$

Thus $\oint _{\gamma }f(z)\,dz=\dfrac{2 i \pi }{3}$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** From $z^3-1=(z-1)(z^2+z+1)$ look at the following function $g(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}$. Then from [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), since $1 \in \{ z : | z − 1| < 1\}$
$$g(1)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z−1|=1} \frac{g(z)}{z-1}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z−1|=1} \frac{1}{z^3-1}dz$$

Comment: The function $g(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}$ has poles at $-\frac12 \pm i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$.  Is either or both enclosed by $|z-1|=1$?  You might consider stating something about the analyticity, or lack thereof, of $g$ on $|z-1|\le 1$..

Comment: True, one in quadrant 2 and one in quadrant 3, both outside of $|z−1|\leq 1$, but my answer is only a hint.

Answer (score 1):

*Note:*  The hint of @rtybase is essentially the answer to OPs question. Let's recall *[Cauchy's Integralformula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)*:

If $a$ is in the interior  of $\gamma=\{z:|z-1|=1\}$ and a function $g$ is holomorphic in a region which contains the closure of the interior of $\gamma$, then
\begin{align*}
g(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma} \frac{g(z)}{z-a}\,dz
\end{align*}

> We have the following situation:
>
> The function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^3-1}$ has three simple poles at $z_0=1$ and  $z_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{2}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. The pole $z_0=1$ is in   the interior of $\gamma$. We can write $f(z)$ as
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)=\frac{1}{z^3-1}=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z^2+z+1)}
> \end{align*}
>   and observe: Since $g(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}$ is holomorph in the interior  of  $\gamma$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> g(1)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma} \frac{g(z)}{z-1}\,dz\\
> &=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{(z-1)(z^2+z+1)}\,dz\\
> &=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We finally conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \oint_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz=2\pi i\, g(1)=\frac{2\pi i}{3}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Determine which roots of the denominator are contained within the given curve $|z - 1| = 1$, find the residues at those roots, and calculate using the Residue Theorem.