# How do I solve this complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

$$\displaystyle\int_c\frac{2z-1}{z^2-1}\ dz$$

where $c$ is a circle radius $1$ centred at $1$.

I know it has poles at $i$ and $-i$ but these don't fall within the contour so I'm not sure i can use cauchy's residue theorem. Is the integral just $0$ or is there another way to work it out? Do I work out the path integral?

Comment: This is a contour integral, yes?

Comment: Since the poles don’t lie inside $c$, you are integrating a holomorphic function around a closed path, whence the integral is $0$ by Cauchy’s theorem.

Comment: yes its a contour integral

Comment: 1) @AlonsoDelfín Why are you answering in a comment? 2) Are you entirely certain that the poles are $\pm i$?

Comment: i think so, does the denominator not equal 0 when z is +/-i?

Comment: @EllieMorrissey What is $i^2-1$? Take your time, do it right.

Comment: @Arthur : you’re right. Since the OP said it, I took for granted that the poles are $\pm i$, I didn't even look at the function, my bad. OP: the poles aren’t $\pm i$, in fact the poles are $\pm 1$, and $1$ does lie inside $c$. So you just need to compute the residue at $1$ and use Cauchy’s integral formula.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Why are you answering in a comment? Again?

Comment: @Arthur https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19992/206395

Comment: @EllieMorrissey you could use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372902/complex-integration-using-cauchys-theorem/2372924#2372924) as an example.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín why did I get $i\pi$?

Comment: @R. Burton the answer is indeed $\pi i$. One checks that the residue at $1$ is $1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** From [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) (CIF), since $1 \in D=\{ z : | z − 1| < 1\}$ and $-1 \notin D$
$$g(1)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z−1|=1} \frac{g(z)}{z-1}dz$$
where $g(z)=\frac{2z-1}{z+1}$ (check that $g(z)$ satisfies the criteria required by CIF).
Or
$$\int\limits_{|z−1|=1} \frac{g(z)}{z-1}dz=\int\limits_{|z−1|=1} \frac{2z-1}{z^2-1}dz=2\pi \cdot i \cdot g(1)=\pi\cdot i$$

Plenty of examples to understand this technique [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372902/complex-integration-using-cauchys-theorem/2372924#2372924), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658457/evaluate-the-integral-using-partial-fractions-oint-gamma-fraczz4-%E2%88%92-1-mat/2659096#2659096), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299419/using-cauchys-integral-formula-to-solve-int-z-2-fracezz2z-1-d/3299535#3299535), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177845/oint-gamma-frac-1z21dz-on-different-curves/3178077#3178077) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891661/was-int-gamma-frac-sinzz3-dz-calculed-right/2891881#2891881).

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you can always brute-force it.

Let $c:[0,1)\to\Bbb{C}$ be a function mapping the interval $[0,1)$ to your circle.

The usual formula for the contour integral applies

$$\int_c\frac{2z-1}{z^2-1}\ dz=\int_0^1\left(\frac{2c(t)-1}{c(t)^2-1}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}c(t)\right)\ dt$$

Answer (score 1):

The residue at $z=1$ is $\lim_{z\to1}(z-1)\dfrac {2z-1}{z^2-1}=\dfrac 12$.

Thus by the residue theorem,  we get $2\pi i\cdot\dfrac 12=\pi \cdot i$.